# Cannot get Text box to show the value from data binding where data grid shows value

Tags: c#, data-binding

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    productVM = new ProductViewModel();
    SetBindings();
    setupDataGridView();
}

private void SetBindings() {
    "Product.Quantity",
    true,
    DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation,
    "0",
    "#,##0;(#,##0);0"));

    textBoxDescription.DataBindings.Add("Text", productVM, "Product.Description");

    dataGridViewProducts.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    dataGridViewProducts.DataSource = productVM.Products;
}
```

When running program data shows in DataGrid but doesn't show in text box for Quantity and description. Please help

Comment: In the controleer the Databinding for Text box didnt copy properly; here is right one:

Comment: textBoxQuantity.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", productVM, "Product.Quantity", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, "0", "#,##0;(#,##0);0"));

Comment: You can store the data 1st in the code behind. Like, `string Desc = DataGrid.Rows[0].Text` and then throw it to the textBox